# Listen to PanResponder to change state values

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm pretty new to React Native and I'm facing a problem:

I understood the transformations that you can do with a `PanResponder` and then using the `interpolate` function.

Example:

```
let cardOpacity = {opacity: this.state.pan.x.interpolate({inputRange: [-150, 0, 150], outputRange: [0.9, 0, 0.9]})};
```

The problem I'm facing is a bit more tricky because I want to extract values from this interpolation and not any style:

I want that code to work basically:

```
_renderApplyOrDislikeHint() {
  let cardOpacity = {opacity: this.state.pan.x.interpolate({inputRange: [-150, 0, 150], outputRange: [0.9, 0, 0.9]})};
  let value = {opacity: this.state.pan.x.interpolate({inputRange: [-150, 0, 150], outputRange: [1, 0, 1]})};
  this.state.pan.x.addListener(({value}) => {
    this.x = value._value
    console.log('Value changed', this.x);
  });
  let dimensionStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: this.props.cardWidth,
    height: this.props.cardHeight,
    position: 'absolute'
  };
  return (
    <Animated.View style={[dimensionStyle, cardOpacity]}>
      {this.renderHint()}
    </Animated.View>
  )
}

renderHint(){
  console.log('X in render hint', this.x)
  return this.x > 0 ? <Text>Yes</Text> : <Text>Nope</Text>
}
```

The problem is that animated value work great for styles but they do not force the re-rendering of the `renderHint()` function.
And it is a very bad idea to change state during the render process.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Soooo, I found a solution

Basically in React, the views are listening to the state of the component: so to "re-render" we need to change the state.

Therefore I added a simple change in the pan responder:

```
onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
    this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: this.state.pan.y._value});
    this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
    this.state.pan.x.addListener(({value}) => {
      if (value < 0 && this.state.right){
        this.setState({right: false})
      }
      else if (value > 0 && !this.state.right){
        this.setState({right: true})
      }
    });
}
```

And then just listen to the property:

```
renderHint(){
  return this.state.right > 0 ? <Text>Right</Text> : <Text>Left</Text>
}
```